# Why in Rubik cube moves can be combined in any sequence?

Tags: group-theory

This is from visual group theory by Nathan Carter.

It mentions that moves can be combined in any sequence, where move is rotation by 90 degrees of face of rubik cube.

How is that $a(bc) = (ab)c ?$

Comment: Maybe think about why composition of functions is associative : that is $f \circ (g \circ h) = (f \circ g) \circ h$.

Comment: i am visualizing cube and its not associative if we take top face and left and right face

Comment: Associative is not commutative...

Comment: @Arthur What do you try to say ?

Comment: $a(bc)$ means first you do $bc$ to the cube then you do $a$. And $bc$ means first you do $c$ to the cube then you do $b$. So, in summary, $a(bc)$ means first you do $c$, then you do $b$, then you do $a$. You can check that this is the same as $(ab)c$.

Comment: It's much simpler than you think - all functions in the world are trivially associative no matter what they are doing to the elements. Consider f,g,h three functions f: X -> X. Then f o (g o h) = (f o g) o h. Why? Because (g o h) literally means "the function that operates by first applying h, then g" (i.e. right element first, then left). So to apply f o (g o h) we first need to apply "(g o h)" and to apply that we first apply h and then g. Finally we apply f - i.e. f(g(h(x))). To apply (f o g) o h, we first apply h, and then (f o g) meaning first g and finally f - i.e. again f(g(h(x))).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Association of Rubik moves is so trivial it can be hard to spot.

Consider the move TLF (Top face a quarter turn, then Left face a quarter turn, then Front face a quarter turn). If we first do T, then do LF, we get the same result as we do when we first do TL, then do F. In other words, T(LF) = (TL)F. The Rubik's cube is associative.

Comment: i think confusion arises because of the same colors.

Comment: What do you mean "the same colours"?

Comment: when we rotate top face then the top side of left face (red orih=ginally all tiles) gets replaced by yellow (front face color)

Comment: Yes, this is true. That's how a Rubik's cube works. What are you trying to say? Which part of my answer are you having trouble with?

Comment: No its just that i need to but a rubic cube to see it. can't visualize

Comment: the binary function here is the rotation by 90 degree ? am i right ?

Comment: What binary function? Do you mean group operation? No, the _elements_ of the group (or generators, rather) are 90 degree rotations. The group operation is composition; doing one rotation after the other.

Comment: i see, Thanks...

Answer (score -2):

As Arthur stated, its trivial and therefore strangely hard to spot; I came here with the same question. People seem to be misled when trying to think in terms of ordering compositions of transformations. Its not so simple as (F ∗ U) ∗ R where ∗ means "then perform"; because they then think logically to apply PEMDAS to F ∗ (U ∗ R) where parentheses also suggests "do this first, then perform...". It fails because the cube is obviously non-abelian, you can't "F then do UR". This points out the failure of good notation (and therefore explanation). (I think) its made most clear by Janet Chen in her writeup [Group Theory and the Rubik’s Cube](http://people.math.harvard.edu/~jjchen/docs/Group%20Theory%20and%20the%20Rubik's%20Cube.pdf)

> If C is an oriented cubie, we will write M(C) for the oriented cubicle
>   that C ends up in after we apply the move M, with the faces of M(C)
>   written in the same order as the faces of C. That is, the first face
>   of C should end up in the first face of M(C), and so on. For example,
>   the move R puts the ur cubie in the br cubicle, with the u face of the
>   cubie lying in the b face of the cubicle and the r face of the cubie
>   lying in the r face of the cubicle. Thus, we write R(ur) = br. First,
>   let’s investigate what a sequence of two moves does to the cubie. If
>   M1 and M2 are two moves, then M1 ∗ M2 is the move where we first do M1
>   and then do M2. The move M1 moves C to the cubicle M1(C); the move M2
>   then moves it to M2(M1(C)). Therefore, (M1 ∗ M2)(C) = M2(M1(C)). To
>   show that ∗ is associative, we need to show that (M1 ∗ M2) ∗ M3 = M1 ∗
>   (M2 ∗ M3) for any moves M1, M2, and M3. This is the same as showing
>   that (M1 ∗ M2) ∗ M3 and M1 ∗ (M2 ∗ M3) do the same thing to every
>   cubie. That is, we want to show that (M1 ∗ M2) ∗ M3 = M1 ∗ (M2 ∗
>   M3) for any cubie C. We know from our above calculation that (M1
>   ∗ M2) ∗ M3 = M3(M1 ∗ M2) = M3(M2(M1(C))). On the other hand,
>   M1 ∗ (M2 ∗ M3) = (M2 ∗ M3)(M1(C)) = M3(M2(M1(C))). So, (M1 ∗ M2)
>   ∗ M3 = M1 ∗ (M2 ∗ M3). Thus, ∗ is associative.

Hope that helps.